# Django - CSS path not found

Tags: css, django

**Output in console when server is running:**

```
Not Found: /css/bootstrap.css
```

I'm pretty sure I'm getting the paths wrong but I don't know what are the right paths given my project structure (below).

**settings.py:**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**project tree:**

```
Grand Folder
   app1  
      settings.py
      static
          app1
             css
                bootstrap.css
   app2
   app3
   templates
    base.html
```

**base.html:**

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <title>{% block title %}User test{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use in your **base.html** the `static` template tag:

**EDIT**

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "app1/css/bootstrap.css" %}" />
```

Comment: This shows a warning in the editor: "Tag start is not closed", additionally, this is what the console outputs when server is running: `[11/May/2017 00:34:18] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.css%20/%3E%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EUser%20test%3C/title%3E%3C/head%3E%3Cbody%3E%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20id= HTTP/1.1" 404 1936`

Comment: now it's just returning a `404`, and the warning about the tag is still there. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: just did. Same as above. return 404 and gives tag warning in editor.

Comment: Still not working, still the same warning in editor. This is how my base.html file [looks like](https://pastebin.com/cb89L7Ep) after your suggestion (`somal` is basically `app1`), and here's [my project tree screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/CFin2). I appreciate your attempts to help so I figured I will leave no room for mistakes on my part.

Comment: I still see a 404 in the console, and the editor is still complaining about an unclosed open tag. I think something in the syntax is off and it's not even attempting the path?

Comment: @zerohedge obviously you have one/more syntax errors in your html template code. Also the folder structure doesn't look quite right.

Comment: hmm. The folder structure follows the recommendation in Django's docs. The only highlighted syntax error right now is your link rel above. Weird.